# Is there a game engine that does not use D3D or OpenGL?

Tags: 2d

Is there a game engine that does not use a graphics API such as OpenGL or DX? I want a simple 2D game engine for use in my simple game console.

Comment: How do you plan to output graphics without a graphics API?

Comment: You dont have to use the graphics part of those engines. Most engines come with a lean and mean custom configuration, for instance for a server which has no graphics either.

Comment: I am use a base Graphic in Basic Language for draw

Comment: What is a game engine without graphics?

Comment: @Vahab: "I am use a base Graphic in Basic Language for draw" Could you be a little more specific about this? What is "a base Graphic"? Are you saying that you're using BASIC, the language, to make your game? Which BASIC; there are *innumerable* dialects of BASIC.

Comment: What is your "simple game console," exactly? Are you looking for something that will perhaps run on some home-made hardware?

Answer (score 5):

Allegro 4.x is probably the closest you're going to get to this. It has pure software blitting for 2D sprites. Granted, it will still need to use DirectX to draw to the screen, but that would be more or less true for anything.

That being said, you said this:

> i want a Simple 2D GameEngine for use in my simple game console.

This statement suggests that you equate software rendering to "simple". This is not the case.

There's nothing inherently complex about using OpenGL or D3D to do 2D rendering. Indeed, the whole purpose of using a game engine is to *abstract* the details away, so that you don't directly have to do any of that stuff. You don't have to care about OpenGL or D3D code to use [Allegro 5](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/) or [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/); they handle all of that transparently.

So really, just use a good engine; don't bother yourself about the minor details.

Answer (score 1):

Running without a graphics API is not necessarily simpler.  In fact what you're talking about here is a software rasterizer, which is going to be orders of magnitude more complex than using a graphics API.  It will also be custom code so if you hit any problems with it you won't be able to get help as easily.

Answer (score 0):

First-part Answer: [id Tech 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doom_engine) (aka DOOM engine)

Second-part Answer: A simple 2D game is a fun way to learn. Go ahead :)